# Remove words connected with periods or full stops in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

How to remove words connected with periods using regex in python. 
`ex: for a string 'random random 123.4445.764 random goo.34.hi random'`, the operation returns `'random random random random'`

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.sub`

**Demo:**

```
import re
s =  'random random 123.4445.764 random goo.34.hi random'
print(re.sub("\w*\.\w*", "", s))
```

**Output:**

```
random random  random  random
```

Answer (score 1):

To match words connected with periods, you could use:

[`\b\w+(?:\.\w+)+\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/FvOklF/1)

Updated with comment from [@Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231450/jan)

**Details**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\w+` Match one or more word characters
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.\w+` Match a dot and one or more times a word character
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat one or more times to match `a.b` or `a.b.c` etc
- `\s*` Match zero or more times a whitespace character.

For example:

```
import re
str =  'random random 123.4445.764 random goo.34.hi random'
print(re.sub("\\b\w+(?:\.\w+)+\s*", "", str))
```

That would give you:

> random random random random

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/ZNSHB25951)

Comment: @Jan Thank you for your advice. That would be better indeed! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative not using regex:

```
" ".join(s for s in string.split() if '.' not in s)
#'random random random random'
```